# Clarification about "Gebietsstatus" on tax form

Tags: german-to-english

I want to open a bank account and there is a form about my tax status. Please take a look at the following picture.

[image: Form]

I want to fill in this form but I don't know which option is for me. I am from Iran and have resident permit in Germany and also a tax number. Which one of these words is for me? Gebietsansässig or Gebietsfremd? And what are those options below ( look at attached pic ) please also tell me about Steuerinländer and Steuerausländer.

Comment: According to the note, there should be another note (first line: ... auf dem beigefügten Merkblatt) which you should have received. I wouldn't like to answer this, without reading it. The first yellow mark surely doesn't apply, since you are in Germany and come from outside.

Comment: This is all about what tax regulations the bank should assume. If you live in Germany most time of the year, you are *gebietsansässig.* Also, assuming you aren't living on Helgoland or in Büsingen, you are *Steuerinländer* then. The last question is about countries which also tax their citizens living abroad. The U.S. for example does, and if I remember correct, it's one of the very few countries that do. Residents of Büsingen have to give their Swiss TIN here.

Comment: I'd say this is more of a legal question than a language question.

Comment: @Janka Thanks for your comment. So I will select gebietsansässig and Steuerinländer and enter my tax number there.

Comment: That question definitely has a linguistic component in that the usual meanings seem reversed: An *Inländer* in the technical language employed here could be a foreigner residing in Germany, an *Ausländer* a German residing abroad.

Comment: @Janka: Bist Du vom Fach? Von der Gestaltung wirkt es auf mich so, als gäbe es 3 Fälle von gebietsansässig, die unter dem Punkt aufgelistet sind. Insbesondere der Bundeswehrsoldat, der im Ausland stationiert ist, scheint mir auf das Gegenteil dessen zu verweisen, was Du behauptest.

Comment: I agree with userunknown and think @Janka did misunderstand the form. Reza, if you don't have an additional note explaining the questions (or are still unsure after reading that) I **strongly recommend** to approach a bank employee in a face-to-face talk and fill in the form together with him/her.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Unfortunately, I cannot find an additional form explaining the questions ( Just personal information which is not related ). I am confused. My bank have sent these forms to my house and I need to post them in 14 days. I appreciate your suggestion and should go to one of their branch personally. I hate this kind of bureaucracy for just opening a bank account.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gebietsans%C3%A4ssiger Wer seinen gewöhnlichen Aufenthalt in Deutschland hat, ist sowieso gebietsansässig, aber eben auch, wer seinen Wohnsitz nicht in Deutschland hat, weil er gerade langfristig mit der Bundeswehr in Afghanistan ist, oder Austauschstudent in den U.S.A. Und umgekehrt für Angehörige der U.S.-Streitkräfte in Deutschland, aber eben auch für Leute, die ein Konto in Deutschland eröffnen, obwohl sie in den Niederlanden leben. Das soll vorkommen.

Comment: @David Vogt: Those terms are fixed. Until recently, Ausländer wasn't used because a non-German citizen living in Germany is an Ausländer but still a Gebietsansässiger. This form was not updated since then. Now you may be an Ausländer in the sense of citizenship, and Inländer in the sense of the Außenwirschaftsgesetz, and finally there's also the term of Steuerin/ausländer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering this question because it is of linguistic interest. It is about a case where the common and technical meanings of a term are reversed.

Duden defines [Ausländer](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Auslaender) as

> Angehöriger eines fremden Staates; ausländischer Staatsangehöriger

However, paragraph 2 subparagraph 15 of the *Außenwirtschaftsgesetz* ([AWG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/awg_2013/__2.html)) defines *Inländer* as

> natürliche Personen mit Wohnsitz oder gewöhnlichem Aufenthalt im Inland

and derives *Ausländer* in subparagraph 5 as

> Ausländer sind alle Personen […], die keine Inländer sind.

Therefore, a foreign citizen residing in Germany is an *Ausländer* in common parlance, but an *Inländer* in the technical sense of the AWG. Conversely, a German living abroad is not an *Ausländer* in common parlance, but they are in the technical sense.

(The terms *gebietsansässig* and *gebietsfremd* are from an older revision of the relevant law; they are defined similarly.)

The second part you highlighted is not of linguistic interest (but note that it is less about *Inländer* versus *Ausländer* and more about *unbeschränkt* versus *beschränkt* steuerpflichtig).